# Need Guidance on Server for Android App

Tags: android

I have an app idea that will need to connect to a server to get account information, other users information, and some other stuff.

I am not savvy on the server side of things.

Do I need a website that is hosted and have the app connect to the website?

Can I use my own computer at home to host?

I pretty much don't know anything about this side of things so any information will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Since you're new to SO (StackOverflow), I'd recommend checking out the FAQ to get a handle on asking good questions and how the community works.  Is the best way to avoid flaming :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out [App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).

It's free for a certain ammount of storage and bandwidth and it runs on Google's infrastructure so you don't need to worry about backup, downtime, or server maintainence.

There's also a framework set up for Android and App Engine to work together in harmony.  Check out this [Google I/O 2011 Session on Android and App Engine.](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/android-app-engine-a-developer-s-dream-combination.html)